# How to search many tables efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

How am I best to search multiple database tables for a user supplied query string and return the information.

Say for example I have 5 tables (Customers, Suppliers, Purchase Orders, Parts, and Employees), and I want to build a single unified search page to search all tables and return the data. The user can put it a query string such as "foo" and I need to search customers.companyName, customers.primaryContact, ... , Employees.lastName

How am I best to efficiently achieve this its not practical to do 5 like selects.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE companyName LIKE '%foo%' OR primaryContact LIKE '%foo%'
```

And I cannot union the data sources together as they have different schemas.

- Using a MS SQL server if that is important.

Comment: You can UNION them, you just have to select columns that are common (or equivalent) from each table vs SELECT *

Comment: I think you need to give us more info about the different schemas

Comment: Some of the columns wont have an equivalent in another table.

Comment: Is the order important - if not just have to have separate select from each table?

Comment: Out of interest how are you presenting your results? ASP.Net / WPF / something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to return the matches by table? 
(i.e. "4 foo Costumers, 3 Parts, etc"). If your answer is No, you can make a UNION like this one:

```
Select match from 
(select name as match from costumers where name like'%foo%' UNION
 select category as match from products where category like'%foo%' ...)
```

PS: writing that in a comment was too messy.